# Raspberry pi shows input to be one when wire is attached to GPIO port and other end of wire is left hanging, when nothing is attached it shows zero

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

The code :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time as time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while True:
    print "input for pin 5 ", GPIO.input(5)
    print "input for pin 6 ", GPIO.input(6)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When no input is applied (no female to female jumper wire attached to the Pi GPIO port 5/6), the input shown is 0 on both the pins.

when just a female to female wire is attached to either of the ports,the other end being in my hand or just floating, the input read is 1.

Is my Raspberry Pi dead ? am I doing something wrong? Tried other jumper wires too, but no avail.

Comment: What would you expect it to read when it is floating?

Comment: @Christian judging by the code, the GPIO has built-in pull-down capability, meaning with no input it should read 0. I missed that at first too, and I don't know enough about the Pi to verify the behavior.

Comment: @Mark I see that now. I'm not particularly familiar with the device. I'm trying to dig into the documentation to see if this functionality is available and under what conditions.

Comment: Does the problem occur when there's no wire connected - just a floating pin?

Comment: @Christian no, it does not, it always shows 0 in that case, only when the wire is connected and the wire is floating, it behaves as such

Comment: probably some supernatural godly powers are into play, tried changing the floating wire, still same behavior, potential difference is in the air

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the wire is acting like some sort of antenna, though I'm surprised that it would pick up enough power to cause a detectable signal. Or maybe it's shorting out to somewhere? Most likely it's just some of that good old electronics black magic. :)